# Why doesnt For Loop wait for settimeout; HTML

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, settimeout

I'm making a simple test site to see how to change the color of a page to dark mode, and I'm coming across a few issues.

My requirements for the page were that

```
- the page doesnt just change color immediately, but rather changes the rgb value by + or - 1. (so that its a smooth transition)
```

The problem is that the for loop does not want to wait for the timeout. I found another user who had a similar problem, and someone suggested a callback. The callback did not work for me.

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('theme')){
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light')
}
function changeColor(){
    let theme = localStorage.getItem('theme')
    if (theme === 'dark'){
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light')
        for (let i=30;i<255;i++){
            setTimeout(() => {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + [i,i,i].join(',') + ')';
            }, 100);
        }
    } else{
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark')
        for (let i=255;i>30;i--){
            setTimeout(() => {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + [i,i,i].join(',') + ')';
            }, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using CSS for the transition?

Comment: SetTimeout does not wait, it just schedules the callback

Comment: Your usage of settimeout basically creates a bunch callbacks that then all get executed after 100 ms. Consider an Promise based pattern with async / await or .then() instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7f263goa/1/
... but i would just suggest just adding a data-attribute setting data-theme light or dark. to body and style accordingly via CSS

Comment: @cozycoder I managed to adapt your fiddle. Thanks.